# Is there a way to save entire facebook webpage?

Tags: html, facebook, pdf, web-scraping

I was using this technique:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101738/is-there-a-way-to-download-an-entire-facebook-page

but after the new facebook layout it does not work.

The PDF i save only saves the visible section of the webpage.

Comment: is it for a licit purpose?

Comment: using or creating a web scraper

Comment: no just want to save it as a pdf

Comment: yes it is licit. Just want to save webpage nothing fishy here